# Is a normal irreducible separable polynomial of degree $p$ over a field of characteristic $p$ necessarily Artin-Schreier

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, positive-characteristic

Is a normal irreducible separable polynomial of degree $p$ over a field of characteristic $p$ necessarily Artin-Schreier? If it is true, I am also wondering whether we can generalize this in the following sense.

Let $K$ be a perfect field of characteristic $p$. We say that a normal irreducible polynomial $f(X) \in K[X]$ is cyclic if the corresponding Galois group is cyclic. Let $f(X) \in K[X]$ be cyclic of degree $p^n$, $f(\theta) = 0$. Then $K(\theta)/K$ is a cyclic Galois extension of degree $p^n$, hence a tower of Artin-Schreier extensions $K \subsetneq K_1 \subsetneq \cdots \subsetneq K_{n-1} \subsetneq K_n = K(\theta)$. Do we always have that $\theta$ is an Artin-Schreier generator of $K_n$ over $K_{n-1}$?

I am not familiar with the Artin-Schreier-Witt theory, and I apologize if the question is a standard result. Please provide me with a reference if that is the case.

Comment: $f\in K[x]$ is Artin Schreier with root $\beta$ iff it has degree $p=char(K)$, $\beta\not \in K$ and $\sigma(\beta)=\beta+n,p\nmid n$ where $\sigma(\beta)$ is a different root. Then 
$\sigma(\beta^2)=\beta^2+2n\beta+n^2$ so for $p\ne 2$ the minimal polynomial of $\beta^2$ isn't Artin Schreier, and $\sigma(\beta^2)\ne \beta^2$ implies that $K(\beta^2)=K(\beta)$. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%E2%80%93Schreier_theory) says ("Conversely...") there exists a polynomial in your field generator $\theta$ which is Artin Schreier.

Comment: Dear @reuns I made the following observation, which made me think that the situation holds at least for finite fields. Let $K = \mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ and $L = \mathbb{F}_{p^{n+1}}$. Suppose $\theta$ is an A-S generator of $L$ over $K$. Then $\theta^{\prime}$ is another A-S generator if and only if $\theta^{\prime} = i \theta + c$, where $i \in \mathbb{F}_p \setminus \{ 0 \}$ and $c \in K$. Thus the total number of A-S generators is $(p-1) p^n = p^{n+1} - p^n$. Hence every $x \in L \setminus K$ is an A-S generator. Please let me know if I have some error in my argument in that case.

Comment: $\Bbb{F}_{p^{pn}}/\Bbb{F}_{p^n}$ is A-S, $\Bbb{F}_{p^{n+1}}$ is not a subfield of $\Bbb{F}_{p^n}$ for $n> 1$

Comment: Thank you! A really silly error on my part.

Comment: But your idea was not so bad, looking at the elements such that $\sigma(\gamma)=\gamma+u$ with $u\in K^*$ and $\sigma$ the generator of the Galois group, they are all of the form $i\beta+c,(i,c)\in K^* \times K$ (because $\sigma(\beta/\gamma)=\beta/\gamma\implies \beta/\gamma\in K$) so $\pmatrix{* & *\\ 0 & 1}\subset GL_2(K)$ acts transitively and (since the stabilizer of $\beta$ is trivial) faithfully on those generalized A-S elements.

Comment: Could you please explain why $\sigma(\beta / \gamma) = \beta / \gamma$?

Comment: I meant $\sigma(\beta-i\gamma)=\beta-i\gamma$ ($\beta / \gamma$ is for Kummer extensions, not A-S)